# Multilevel Feedback queue preemptive - resumption

Tags: operating-system, cpu, scheduler

Suppose I have a multilevel feedback queue with two round robins queues having time quanta 1 sec and 2 sec respectively.
Now let us consider a situation where two processes P1,P2 are in the second queue(lower priority) and P1 gets scheduled and after 1 second ( that is before the time quanta of P1 expired) process P3 comes into the top queue.

Since top queue is higher priority P1 is preempted and P3 is scheduled and after P3 is complete, now in the second queue, does P1 is resumed to complete its remaining time quanta (or) P2 is scheduled with a new timer

Comment: Run through your scheduling algorithm with the above data.  What did you find out?

Comment: I'd say that depends on the actual implementation.